# How can I prevent div overflow with container width 100%

Tags: css, html, alignment

I am trying to find a neat way to get my header to have a width of 100% (so I can use a background colour that spreads across the whole page), but also within it I have two images, that I'd like to stay inline and not overflow on each other or push each other down.

I currently have the follow CSS:

```
header {    
width: 100%;
height: 150px;  
padding: 50px 50px 10px 50px;
clear: both;
background: #185f96;}

#logo {
float: left;
width: 800px;}
```

`#phone { float: left; width: 200px; }`

Logo and phone are inside the header. If you look at it in action (removed) you can see if you size it down to a certain point, the phone info gets pushed under the banner. I can set it to a static width, but then this is an issue with different web sizes.

I created an extra div inside the header in which I just put the logo, and left the phone on the outside. This gives me the results I want, but I want wondering if there was a neater way of achieving this without the extra div.

(Also sorry for the formatting of the code section, I have trouble getting it to be neatly formatted. Doesn't seem to work properly)

Comment: @MrLister : `oveflow: hidden;` hides the problem, not solves it... :)

Comment: @NoobEditor With smaller screens, the two images are just too wide to fit in the window. The only solution is to hide stuff when it overflows, or to start resizing the images.

Comment: Wow, so simple. Thank you. Is there a fix that doesn't hide but makes it function that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce your page with and use % unit in padding too as.

```
header {    
width: 84%;
height: 150px;  
padding: 5% 5% 1% 5%;
clear: both;
background: #185f96;}

#logo {
float: left;
width: 800px;}
```

Comment: Before I do this, if you look at what i've done, the header is currently 100%, which is displaying at 2004px. So even at 100%, it seems to be way wider than all my content. I can't seem to spot what is forcing 100% to be 2004px.

Comment: The body has no padding or margin and is therefore as wide as the window. The header has width 100%, but in addition it also has a 50px padding, which makes its total width wider than the body. Solution: remove said padding.

Comment: your window is 2004px.
Your left and right padding is 50px + 50px =100px
So your total width will be 2104px.
So either use % in width and padding or use px in both of them.

Comment: Yep, solved. Silly inconsistency by me. However after this I still need overflow hidden.

Comment: The sum of all % (width + padding-right +padding-left) must me 100%. Or you will see scroll bar instead.

Comment: After making some changes to other sections, this doesn't seem to work anymore. My total header width is 100%, but when I resize it down, it still pushes down the phone graphic. I have both clear: both and overflow: hidden on the header and this problem is still occuring.

Answer (score 0):

Set `width` is percentage and then add `white-space:nowrap;` to `header` to prevent things from to a new line

```
header {    
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;  
    padding: 50px 50px 10px 50px;
    clear: both;
    background: #185f96;
    white-space:nowrap; /*added*/
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    display:inline-block; /* or width in percentage */
}

#phone {    
    float: left;
    min-width: 20%; /* ammended */
}
```